# structure of while loop

Tags: input, while-loop

I am trying to use a while loop in Python to provide an error message while there is a backslash character in the user input. The code provides the error message when a fraction is input and requests a second input. The problem occurs when the second input differs in length from the original input and I do not know how to fix this since my knowledge of Python is limited. Any help is appreciated!

```
size = getInput('Size(in): ')
charcount = len(size)
for i in range(0,charcount):
 if size[i] == '/':
  while size[i] == '/':
   getWarningReply('Please enter size as a decimal', 'OKAY')
   size = getInput('Size(in): ')
 elif size[i] == '.':
#Convert size input from string to list, then back to string because strings are immutable whereas lists are not
  sizechars = list(size)
  sizechars[i] = 'P'
  size = "".join(sizechars)
```

Comment: what language is this? "the language" doesn't tell us much...

Comment: Not trying to be harsh or anything, but the mixture of "FOR", "IF" and "WHILE" seems very strange and I think the logic is properly the first problem, regardless of while syntax in the given language.
I'd advice you to go back to the beginning and take it from there, reworking the logic

Comment: Sorry, it's Python. Yes, I know it's messy but I haven't used Python in a few years and I am trying to brush up on it.

Comment: The problem that I'm having is that when the user provides the second input, it gives an error if it is a different size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a good way to go about doing what you want because if the length of the new `size` is shorter than the original length, `charcount`, then you can easily go out of range.

I'm by no means a Python master, but an easily better way to do this is to wrap the entire thing in a while loop instead of nesting a while loop within the for loop:

```
not_decimal = True

while not_decimal:
    found_slash = False
    size = getInput('Size(in): ')
    charcount = len(size)

    for i in range(0, charcount):
        if size[i] == '/':
            print 'Please enter size as a decimal.'
            found_slash = True
            break
        elif size[i] == '.':
            #Convert size input from string to list, then back to string because strings are immutable whereas lists are not
            sizechars = list(size)
            sizechars[i] = 'P'
            size = "".join(sizechars)

    if not found_slash:
        not_decimal = False
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a ton. As everyone can tell, I am very rusty on statement/loop structure. I really appreciate it. I would vote up if I could, but it says I need 15 reputation lol.